# Webpack watcher on fast changing Sources

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I´m using Webpack with the --watch tag, which works realy fine for me.
The only problem in my deployment process is:
Sometimes I use gulp to reaplce some lines of my Sourcecode. Because of that the "watched" Sources could change very fast, probably faster then webpack is executed. As result of that my webpack watcher doesn´t react to changes any more.
Does someone of you have a hint for me how to solve that problem ?
Is there an option to timeout the watcher and trigger it again after my replacements by the gulp process or something like that ?

Answer (score 0):

watchOptions.aggregateTimeout
(only used when using CLI or simple node.js API)

Delay the rebuilt after the first change. Value is a time in ms.

Default: 300

you can see more details in https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#watch

Comment: "call webpack --progress --watch --watchOptions.aggregateTimeout 3000"
So it should look sth equal to that ?
Saidly it doesn´t work